# Filter data between "NBA" in 'Column C' and the last row of 'Column D' with numbers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to filter only the data that starts with `NBA` in `Column C` and **finish the filter on the last row that has numbers**, because below that last number starts the data from another league, which doesn't interest me. As it is imported data, the values will always change rows so I can't make a fixed formula, it needs to be flexible.

**One detail** is that the `NBA` can be in any row of `Column C`, it will not always be specifically in the first row.

[image]

Splitting the data into two columns I already managed, but I couldn't come up with a way to filter this data.

I tried to tweak this basic formula in several ways:
`=FILTER(C:D,FIND("NBA",C:C,0),ISNUMBER(D:D))`
But I got no results.

Link to Spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LPaRYQmsFun-ftTioIo6mKotlnRI-JiZZnqRS-O3ias/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get position NBA and last number in B after NBA like this

```
= filter 
  (
    A10:B26,
    row(A10:B26)>=filter(row(A10:A26),A10:A26="NBA"), 
    row(A10:A26)<min(filter(row(B10:B26),row(A10:B26)>filter(row(A10:A26),A10:A26="NBA"),isnumber(B10:B26)=false))
  )
```

[image]